# Serving two different version of php applications

Tags: php, nginx

I am trying to run two almost identical php application in nginx. It's a temp solution due to minor api changes. I would like to use a query string such as `v=testing` and have nginx serve different app.

using ubuntu 16.04, nginx/1.10.3, PHP 7.0.33

`example.com_2` is the second php app. I have tried the following:

```
server {
    server_name example.localhost;
    root   /var/www/example.com/public;
    index index.php index.html;
    listen 80;

    include php_biz.conf;
}

location / {
    if ($arg_v = testing) {
        root /var/www/example.com_2/public;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location ~ .*\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404; # 404 if file doesnt exist
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass   php_biz;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
upstream php_biz {
    server unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm-biz.sock;
}
```

When I access `example.com_2` php app, I am getting 404 from nginx not from php app. Accessing static file from `example.com_2` works.

So it looks like setting root in the `if` block does nothing for the php app and works for the static. What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with maps:

```
map $arg_v $app_suffix {
    default "";
    testing "_2";
}
server {
    server_name example.localhost;
    root   /var/www/example.com${app_suffix}/public;
    index index.php index.html;
    listen 80;

    include php_biz.conf;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location ~ .*\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404; # 404 if file doesnt exist
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass   php_biz;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
upstream php_biz {
    server unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm-biz.sock;
}
```